# send http request from onChange handler or from useEffect: what is better

Tags: reactjs

Which approach is better or less good, in sense of react rendering performances?

**sending request from onChange handler,**

```
<Select
  selectOpts={years}
  onChange={(event: any) => {
    sendRequest(event.target.value).then((res: any) => {
      setResults(res.data);
    });
    setYear(event?.target.value);
  }}
  value={year ?? ''}
  label='Year'
/>
```

**or set the state inside onChange hanlder and trigger request via useEffect**

```
useEffect(() => {
  sendRequest(event.target.value).then((res: any) => {
    setResults(res.data);
  });
}, [year])

<Select
selectOpts={years}
  onChange={(event: any) => {
    setYear(event?.target.value);
  }}
  value={year ?? ''}
  label='Year'
/>
```

I would say the latter is more cleaner in a way that keeps responsibility of handler just to change the state, and does not care about request. Anyway i am curious to hear for more prons and cons, if any.

Answer (score 0):

The latter approach involving `useEffect` is discouraged, as stated in this recent article from React beta docs:

[You Might Not Need an Effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect).

From the same artical: You don’t need Effects to handle user events. For example, let’s say you want to send an /api/buy POST request and show a notification when the user buys a product. In the Buy button click event handler, you know exactly what happened. By the time an Effect runs, you don’t know what the user did (for example, which button was clicked). This is why you’ll usually handle user events in the corresponding event handlers.

##### As it describe the purpose of Effect:

Effects are an escape hatch from the React paradigm. They let you “step outside” of React and synchronize your components with some external system like a non-React widget, network, or the browser DOM. If there is no external system involved (for example, if you want to update a component’s state when some props or state change), you shouldn’t need an Effect. Removing unnecessary Effects will make your code easier to follow, faster to run, and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

Perfomance wise it would be better to use useRef.

Perfomance gains are not much, so keep it simple as you did, I would destructure to be cleaner:

```
<Select
  selectOpts={years}
  onChange={({target: {value}) => {
    sendRequest(value).then(({data}) => {
      setResults(data);
    });
    setYear(value);
  }}
  value={year ?? ''}
  label='Year'
/>
```